# How do I achieve data span across multiple regions (not replication) with Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-partitioning

I have a single Azure SQL Server and a single database in it. I want a solution to store specific records of selected tables in this database in different regions. 
as an example, I have a users table with all PII data in it. these users can be from anywhere from the world. but i would want to store user records who are from EU region to be stored only in EU region. 
To add it - i want all the other table records related to a specific user as well to get stored in that user's region.

from application perspective, i would be able to query across all users and all related tables to have dashboard data for the global users.

Any pointers to solve this scenario would be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be sharding the database. Use horizontal sharding to store the rows for each country/region in a separate database in that country/region. The Elastic Database Client library will use a shardmap do most of the sharding work for you (assuming you are using .NET). You can use the country code in your shardmap to split regional data.

[image]

Reference Architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/sharding

Elastic Database Client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-database-client-library

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach... When your user/tenant registers for your service they will need to pick where their data should reside.  This is referred to as data residency. Then on subsequent requests to read or write data your application's repository layer needs to be aware of who the request is executing as so it can lookup the appropriate connection string and connect to that database to retrieve/write the data.

The routing data can be replicated to multiple regions and/or housed in a single location as it would not contain PII.  The Azure Web App can be single region hosted (as depicted in the image below) or it can be replicated to multiple regions and traffic routed to it via a global traffic manager.

This approach supports the case where an European user picks to have their data reside in France but happens to be visiting the united states.

This picture shows how this might look.  A guy named Barry Luijbregts has a nice pluralsight video that delves into this approach.  https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/azure-paas-building-global-app

Good luck!

[image: Dynamic routing image]